# chosen selecting previous value in new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen plugin and when i add row in html table dynamically ,new select box comes with previous value and becomes not editable. I know problem is caused by having same id's of select boxes but i cant change id because it will effect functionality of my application.Please help!!

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique anyway  coz having duplicate IDs is not allowed and  wont do any good.

Comment: I know sir,but previous developers used them and now i cant fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

use html5 "data" attribute, get a look at documentation here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

jquery functon doc page here :

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Good luck :)